# Properly using exceptions

Tags: java, c#, c++, exception, callstack

I'm not certain to perfectly undertand the way exceptions should be used. I often wonder "do i have to catch this here, or higher in the call stack ?" and things like that. But i've created a small exception class to have some kind of C#-like exception that can show a stack of exceptions :

```
class Exception : public std::exception
{
protected:

   std::string _trace;

public:

   Exception()
    : _trace( "[ERROR - " + (std::string) DateTime() + "]"
   { }

   Exception & push( const std::string & msg )
   {
      this->_trace += '\n\t' + msg;
      return *this;
   }

   virtual const char * what() const
   {
      return this->_trace.c_str();
   }
};
```

Which i can use like this :

```
function depth0()
{
    try
    {
        depth1();
    }
    catch( Exception & exc )
    {
        throw exc.push( "depth0() - Failed." );
    }
}

function depth1()
{
    try
    {
        depth2();
    }
    catch( Exception & exc )
    {
        throw exc.push( "depth1() - Failed." );
    }
}

function depth2()
{
    try
    {
        depth3();
    }
    catch( Exception & exc )
    {
        throw exc.push( "depth2() - Failed." );
    }
}

function depth3()
{
    if( something goes wrong )
    {
        throw Exception().push( "depth3() - Failed." );
    }
}

try
{
    depth0();
}
catch( Exception & exc )
{
    std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
}
```

I don't have to catch and throw at every single depth of the callstack, that's just an example.

Is this a correct way to use exceptions ? isn't it against the philosophy of exceptions ? (which i don't understand yet).

Thank you :)

PS : I used Java and C# tags because this is all about exceptions in general, even if the samples are in C++.

Comment: You should rarely try-catch in C++ but build your code around RAII-idiom: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: Thanks. I read your article but i don't get the relation with this.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but as a hint for C++: You can rethrow exceptions with `throw;` (no arguments). That means instead of throwing a copy like in your example you would do: `exc.push(...); throw;`

Comment: Read the "benefits" section and try to write exception safe C++ code which allocates memory within a scope using RAII and without

Comment: @Matthias247 Does it throw a copy ? Doesn't it throw the reference ? :o

Comment: Are you recreating [std::nested_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception) ?

Comment: @Cubbi No, no recursivity here, just concatenating error messages in the same exception.

Comment: You catch by reference. But you always throw by value (you can throw pointers, but you should not). When you do `throw exc.(...);` a copy of your modified `exc` object will be created and be thrown instead of the original object.

Comment: Creating this copy also means that your object might by sliced down on that occation to the exception base-type that you specify in the `catch` expression and thereby loose the infromation of the more specific exception object. So it should by avoided.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule: catch a exception where you can handle it. And catch a specific exception where possible. Like connecting to your database - you will never want to have an exception pop up to the user - in worst case containing connection string details. Therefor your business logic layer would have to catch database exceptions and handle it as they can (try again to connect, log the exception etc.) and throw some exception the frontend can savely handle (a custom database connection exception or other that tells no details).

On the other hand something you cannot handle well (out of memory exceptions or such) you can catch at the application level and respond with some (custom if possible but at least generic)  info to the user that something went wrong. If possible bringing the application into a stable state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Makes me a bit less confused about exceptions.